# are modern.ie IE 11 VMs really running Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, modern.ie

I am playing with the http://modern.ie VMs for Windows 7 and 8.1 for IE 11.  Something seems to be off in them -- the "about" box of IE shows IE 11, however when I go into F12 developer tools, they don't look like IE 11 dev tools and they do mention Edge as one of the possible compatibility options.  So are these IE11 VMs really edge masking as IE?

Comment: "Edge" in your context (Developer Tools | Emulation) means "latest and greates for this browser" and is not related to the product "Edge".

Comment: hmmm OK, but why does the UI look all modern and not at all like the normal developer tools in IE11?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe MS decided to upgrade this component at one the updates for IE. I honestly cannot remember when it started looking modern.

Comment: @Filburt Nah, I was just confused because we had multiple screenshots from different IE versions in the same bug report.  IE11 F12 tools do look modern and it is fine. Thank you for your help.  Turned out that it was switching to IE7 compatibility mode for intranet site.